# Powershell Get-ADUser command output print only UserPrincipalName

Tags: powershell

From `Get-ADUser` command I want to display only `UserPrincipalName` values. but for the below command its not displaying any output:

```
Get-ADUser "user1" -Properties "*" |Select-String -Pattern "UserPrincipalName"
```

How to display only this value from the command output?

Thanks

Comment: `(Get-ADUser "user1").UserPrincipalName` or `Get-ADUser "user1" | Select-Object -Expand UserPrincipalName`